# Are developers able to load a specific portion of a website into a company's facebook page

Tags: web, integration, facebook-iframe

I want to know if developers are able to load a specific region of website into their company's Facebook page?  If so, How?  Is anyone else doing it or is there any company Facebook page I can see or reference?

Reason:

To get around the 810 pixel limit and having no ability to adjust the source website I need to show only a portion of the website in Facebook.  When the users hit the link on the portion of the website I want to take them to the appropriate page but stay in Facebook.

Comment: You talking about Facebook applications or pages? Because on pages you can only link to application (which represent your page) or directly to page.